# how to estimate RAM ROM usage from (Text data bss dec hex)

Tags: c, gcc, esp8266, memory-layout, memory-footprint

Hello is it possible to estimate the size of RAM and ROM used from

```
text     data     bss     dec     hex     filename
24823     0       920    25743    648f    (TOTALS)
```

I read on some blog "RAM = Data + bss" is that correct??. 
The target hardware is ESP8266 (ESP 12)

Comment: ROM? I guess you should add a target platform (at least) for clarification.

Comment: In the general case, this is **not** correct. Even when assuming you're targeting some embedded platform (so your `text`, the actual code, ends up in ROM / flash), your code still needs **at least** some stack space. You'd have to add the sizes of the stack frames at the point of the deepest function nesting at runtime. And then, if the code uses `malloc()`, you have to consider that as well.

Comment: check out the answer given by @tcrosley in this thread

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237740/what-resides-in-the-different-memory-types-of-a-microcontroller/237759

Comment: In addition to what @FelixPalmen said, you can also have `const` data which might end up in Flash, and thus take up ROM space rather than RAM.

Comment: RAM = .data + .bss + .stack + .heap (if applicable). ROM = .text + .rodata + whatever custom segments there might be. There will be segments for CRT (start-up stuff), vector tables etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably uC stuff :)

Almost - but you forgot about the stack and heap. Those values you can take from your linker script

for example:

```
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x300;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x500; /* required amount of stack */
```

Answer (score 0):

In Keil IDE there is a project option for writing listing (map) files containing information about your memory usage of your program. Example:

```
Image component sizes

Code (inc. data)   RO Data    RW Data    ZI Data      Debug   Object Name
  28         10          0          0          0          0   app_error.o

...

Code (inc. data)   RO Data    RW Data    ZI Data      Debug   

 22580       2194        388        232       3904          0   Grand Totals
 22580       2194        388        232       3904          0   ELF Image Totals
 22580       2194        388        232          0          0   ROM Totals
```

==============================================================================

```
Total RO  Size (Code + RO Data)                22968 (  22.43kB)
Total RW  Size (RW Data + ZI Data)              4136 (   4.04kB)
Total ROM Size (Code + RO Data + RW Data)      23200 (  22.66kB)
```

Visual Studio also have such an option.